# Close SP.UI.ModalDialog without returning result

Tags: sharepoint, modal-dialog

I have a SP.UI.ModalDialog. On the dialog there are two radio buttons:

- Agree
- Disagree

Then there is a submit button. The submit button checks to see what the value of the radio button is.

```
OnClick="if(document.getElementById('Agree').checked){var results ={result:'agree'};return SP.UI.ModalDialog.commonModalDialogClose(SP.UI.DialogResult.OK,results);}else{var results ={result:'disagree'};return SP.UI.ModalDialog.commonModalDialogClose(SP.UI.DialogResult.cancel,results)}">
```

Now I want to add a "Close dialog" button, that simply closes the dialog. I don't want it to return any results. How can I simply close the dialog?

The following is not working for me:

```
OnClick="window.frameElement.SP.UI.ModalDialog.commonModalDialogClose();"
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to close SP.UI.ModalDialog from button click in sharepoint?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19320690/how-to-close-sp-ui-modaldialog-from-button-click-in-sharepoint)

Answer (score 0):

For anyone referencing this question in the future, apparently the problem is internet explorer in my dev environment. Not sure if it's so much a browser issue as it is a dev environment issue, though. The same code works in QA with the same version of ie. Will have to investigate my browser settings further in my dev envrmnt.

Answer (score 0):

For what it is worth, I was also struggling with using a button to close a modal window. Passing `null` worked for me.

```
var _html = document.createElement();
_html.innerHTML = 'Something written in here <input type="button" value="Close" onClick="SP.UI.ModalDialog.commonModalDialogClose(1, null)">'
```